# ActionController::UrlGenerationError with POST #create action in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing an e-commerce site, and I'm running into a problem with one of my tests. My test for the create action looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ReviewsController, type: :controller do
    describe "POST #create" do
        before(:each) do
            user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            login user
            @product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
            post :create, params: { blurb: "Lorem ipsum something or other" }
        end

        it "renders the product path" do
            expect(response).to redirect_to(product_path(@product))
        end
    end
end
```

The "login user" line works, which I confirmed with byebug (there is a valid user and session). In this iteration, I get the error that No route matches {:action=>"create", :blurb=>"Lorem ipsum something or other", :controller=>"reviews"}
, even though my rake routes looks like this:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
                root GET    /                                           landings#index
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
       user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                     POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     devise/registrations#cancel
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       devise/registrations#edit
user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#destroy
                     POST   /users(.:format)                            devise/registrations#create
     product_reviews POST   /products/:product_id/reviews(.:format)     reviews#create
  new_product_review GET    /products/:product_id/reviews/new(.:format) reviews#new
             product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                     products#show
             jewelry GET    /jewelry(.:format)                          products#jewelry
            clothing GET    /clothing(.:format)                         products#clothing
         decorations GET    /decorations(.:format)                      products#decorations
```

When I change the post line to look like this:
    post :create, user: user, params: { blurb: "Lorem ipsum something or other" }
I get "key doesn't exist: user". Here's my model:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :product

    validates_presence_of :blurb
end
```

My controller:

```
class ReviewsController < InheritedResources::Base
    respond_to :html
    belongs_to :product
    actions :new

    def create
        @review = Review.new(review_params)
        @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        if user_signed_in?
            @review.user_id = current_user.id
            @review.product_id = params[:product_id]
            if @review.save!
                redirect_to product_path(@product)
            else
                render :new
            end
        else
            redirect_to new_user_session_path
        end
    end

    private

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:blurb, :utf8, :authenticity_token, :commit)
    end
end
```

And my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'landings#index'
    devise_for :users
    resources :products, only: [:show] do
        resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create]
    end
    get '/jewelry', to: 'products#jewelry', as: :jewelry
    get '/clothing', to: 'products#clothing', as: :clothing
    get '/decorations', to: 'products#decorations', as: :decorations
end
```

I'm using Ruby 2.4.0, and Rails 5.1, any help would be appreciated.

//EDIT

I added the FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods to my RSpec config, and refactored to use let and product_id, like so:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ReviewsController, type: :controller do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }
    let(:product) { create(:product) }

    describe "GET #new" do
        before(:each) do
            get :new, params: { product_id: product.id }
        end

        it "renders the new template" do
            expect(response).to render_template(:new)
        end

        it "returns a 200 status code" do
            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
        end
    end

    describe "POST #create" do
        before do
            login user
        end

        context "with valid attributes" do
            let(:action) do
                post :create, product_id: product, params: { review: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:review) }
            end

            it "creates a review" do 
                expect { action }.to change(product.reviews, :count).by(+1)
            end

            it "redirects to the review" do
                action
                expect(response).to redirect_to product.reviews.last
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I am not getting the error "unknown keyword: product_id". I've whitelisted it in the controller params, not sure where to go from here.

Comment: `belongs_to :product` goes in your model - not the controller!

Comment: Good point! That was a copy-paste error on my part, fortunately ;)

Comment: You'll also want to use a `before_action` callback for authentication instead of duplicating the same logic all over your controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route requires a `product_id` param. Besides that your test badly needs proper structuring. You can use the scaffold command in rails if you want to see an example of how to test standard crud controllers.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ReviewsController, type: :controller do

  # use let to setup given variables
  let(:user) {  FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:product) {  FactoryGirl.create(:product) }

  describe "POST #create" do
    before do
      login user
    end

    context "with valid attributes" do
      let(:action) do
        post :create, params: { product_id: product, review: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:review) }
      end

      it "creates a review" do 
        expect { action }.to change(product.reviews, :count).by(+1)
      end

      it "redirects to the review" do
        action
        expect(response).to redirect_to product.reviews.last
      end
    end

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

You should move the authentication to a before filter and cut the duplication and you can condense your controller down quite a bit:

```
# call this whatever you want but DRY it out.
class ApplicationController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_action :authenticate!

  def authenticate!
    redirect_to new_user_session_path and return false unless user_signed_in?
  end 
end 

class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html
  actions :new

  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @review = @product.reviews.new(review_params) do |r|
      r.user = current_user
    end
    # don't use .save! here - it will raise an exception
    # if the record is not valid
    if @review.save
      redirect_to product_path(@product)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def review_params
    # only permit the params that actually should be assigned to the model!
    params.require(:review).permit(:blurb) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax tips, I appreciate that.

Adding the product_id property produces the following error: "unknown keyword: product_id".

Comment: Ah right - in rails 5 you need to put it in params. edited.

Comment: I put it in the reviews_params, but no dice.

Comment: No, you need to pass it in the params key in the spec. `post :create, params: { product_id: product ...`.

Comment: You also seem confused about what the strong params do. It basically lets you filter out a whitelist of params that should be assignable to the model. The rest are discarded. Its not for specifying every parameter the client is allowed to send.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your action route `/products/:product_id/reviews(.:format)` you need to pass `product_id`

So change your spec to:

```
post :create, product_id: @product.id, params: { blurb: "Lorem ipsum something or other" }
```

And you might need to change `actions :new` to `actions :create` in your `ReviewsController`.

---

Also you can add `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` line to your `rails_helper.rb` so you dont need to write `FactoryGirl` every time you call FG method:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  ...
end
```

Here is [link to FG docs about that](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#rspec)

Comment: Adding the product_id property produces the following error: "unknown keyword: product_id". I will make sure it's whitelisted in the controller and fiddle with that.